# is there any way to use static-method without class?

Tags: java, class, methods, static-methods

```
package java;
//----------------------------- add one more line in here
class Demo {
    public static String prt(String name) {
        return "my name:" + name;
    }
}
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(prt("hong"));
    }
}
```

if there is any way to print

> my name : hong

,please let me know.

Comment: Yes, but only within the scope of the same class. If your `prt` method was defined within the `Sample` class then you can just call it directly.

Comment: yes thanks your help. but i know that way. But shoud i put something in "//----------------------------- add one more line in here ".

Comment: I think you are talking about static imports https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html.

Comment: answer it myself.  import static java.Demo.*;
self answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating an instance of the Demo class with `new Demo()`, like this:

```
class Demo {
    public static String prt(String name) {
        return "my name:" + name;
    }
}
class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new Demo().prt("hong"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference it via the class name:

```
Demo.prt("Hong")
```

however, if you can't use class Demo, then I'm not exactly what real life situation this would be.  Methods belong to classes, they do not exist on their own.  They must be referenced by classes, or instances of the class. Unless you're providing more context on your question, the answer is No.

However, if you can reference it by object, you could do this:

```
Demo demo = new Demo();
System.out.println(demo.prt("hong"));
```

Comment: So, the answer to the question in the OP's title is simply "No."

Comment: thanks. but it is kind of test. i can't use that way